# Extending the wing of commercial plane

Tags: wing

**Question No.3**

I was asking my self question related to the payload capacity which is:

*

> If we want to carry more passengers & cargo containers, so it's
> obvious we should increase the wing area

*, but as we know the size of airport road is limited to span of wing approximately 80m, so why we dont extended it longitudinally ??

Is there limitation also due to :

1. Availability of many safe doors as much as possible.
2. Manufacturers dont like to change the old fashion of airplane design, (A380 was made an exceptional development in avaiation history by making 2 decks).
3. or it has relationship with Reynolds number as in wind tunnel test if wing chord is 1m @ density 1.2 Kg/m3, then in high altitude, the chord can be 4m @ density 0.3 Kg/m3 as we want to have the same Reynolds number.
4. Structural or Economical issues.

So, what's the right answer ??

[image]

Comment: Your username is certainly appropriate to the question...

Comment: Still waiting for your airfoil that puts supercritical ones to shame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Induced drag](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Induced_Drag) is the drag created by anything that's creating lift, such as a wing. It's caused by the high pressure air underneath the wing flowing around the end of the wing into the low pressure zone above it. This creates a vortex that in turn creates drag on the wing.

The formula for the coefficient of drag is

$$C_{di} = \frac{C_l^2}{\pi A e}$$

where $C_l$ is the coefficient of lift, $A$ is the aspect ratio of the wing (i.e. the length divided by the chord), and $e$ is the efficiency of the wing's lift (calculated based on its lift distribution; for a perfectly elliptical lift distribution, $e = 1$). Since $A$ is in the denominator of the equation, the bigger it is, the lower the amount of induced drag.

TLDR: Long, thin wings generate less drag than short fat ones.

Comment: you are right in aerodynamic side but someone will comment an inverse question: why we dont decrease the area of wing, so we can decrease the induced drag for recently plane. Definitelly thats mean lowering the capacity of passenger. I think that it has not direct relationship with induced drag because we know that it will be only high in low speed (take-off). Also, increasing area will let us have more space to store fuel which increase therange of flight as double. What i thinks it has relation with reynolds number which limit our chord or the price of ticket -economical

Comment: @peter_kampf If you have account either in Linkedin or Facebook, you may follow hashtag of my development there: #Miracle_Airfoil_Project     - All questions that I have made here is related directly with my new design & until now we reach takeoff phase performance which let us have CL_max=2.7@AoA=18deg for V=60m/s and still we waiting for CFD test of other lower takeoff speeds. I don't thinks it's appropriate to post about that matter here as it's question forum only, but I will not deny, it's helpful forum let me to find experts like YOU & other which oneday I will thanks this great website

Comment: @MiracleAirfoil You misunderstand. It's not the *area* of the wing that's important for that equation, but specifically the *aspect ratio*. If you halve the chord but double the length (all else being equal), the *area* (and therefore lifting ability) stays the same, but the *aspect ratio* goes up by a factor of 4, reducing drag by that same factor.

Comment: This answer has it spot on. A long-chord, low-aspect-ratio wing is aerodynamically inefficient, and that wastes expensive fuel. For the 777X, Boeing therefore calculated that adding folding wingtips was a more cost-efficient way to fly more payload from a standard terminal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777X

Comment: @HiddenWindshield 1) Its my mistake that I dont share with you my assumption to agree for whats next. I have assumed that span of wing & max lift coefficient are constant (max span in airport = 80m), so area (a) is inverse relationship with aspect ratio (AR).
So, induced drag formula, increasing area will lead to increase the induced drag by the same amount.
But, we forget that airplane manufacture doesn't care too much to obtain high speed, they want attract customers (airliner agency) which is related to the price of ticket or you may say [Liter/(Pax.Km)]

Comment: @HiddenWindshield 2) So,when we increase the area by double, we increase the drag eventually, but the number of 
passengers will be also doubled, then rather than carry 500 pax in one plane, we can carry 1000 pax with the same price of ticket.
Concorde has been failed - even it has high cruise speed - obtain percentage of market potential of commercial transportation because the price per passenger is too much high for business men & women. Also, to pay 10 times the ticket price of ordinary plane only to reach your destination in less than half hour is not really worth it.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield 3) As i understand from Concorde, it's not the fuel issue which let to have high price, but the special & expensive material which should withstand high temperature. I dont know how company like BOOM will solve this problem now. Maybe they make market survey & found there are certain people would like to pay more money but not like Concorde palne if it's possible

Comment: @MiracleAirfoil A faster airplane can make more trips per day, carrying more passengers. So, yes, the airline industry _does_ care about making planes fast. That is, after all, why supersonic passenger aircraft were even attempted in the first place. Also, if you double the area, you **DON'T** double the number of passengers. You're forgetting to take into account the added weight of the wing and fuselage structure. So, your $L/P_xK_m$ equation is going to go *up*, not down, with this wing.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield Assume that we have 2 planes each have total gross weight of 250 ton with L/D =20. This 2 planes if it is emerged into ONE plane we will have new parameter which is: Gross weight = 500 ton & L/D=10 (in worst scenario). So why Lift-drag ratio is decreased ? The reason for that our span is limited in the airport up to 80m, so aspect ratio will decrease as a result of increasing Area. In point view of fuel consumption, it's BAD choice, but the advantage of doubling the number of passengers or cargo containers may equalize it as the same of original plane for 250 ton with L/D=20

Comment: @MiracleAirfoil You *yourself* pointed out the desirability of minimizing the $L/PxKm$ equation.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield You are right expert. L/D should be constant for any increase in number of passenger so they will pay the same value of L/Px.Km. Thanks alot for giving me your time. :)